# Github action uploads all intermediary steps using docker/build-push-action using buildx

Tags: docker, github-actions, buildx

**Background**

I have a npm monorepo using turborepo. Now I want to build this to production using github actions.

**The problem**

The docker/build-push-action github action pushes all my intermediary images for a total of three images pushed to my artifact repository. Only one tagged correctly.

**Expected**

Only my one final image (runner) pushed to artifact repo

**My Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:alpine AS builder
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
# Set working directory
WORKDIR /app
RUN npm install turbo --global
COPY . .
RUN turbo prune --scope=admin --docker
 
# Add lockfile and package.json's of isolated subworkspace
FROM node:alpine AS installer
RUN apk add --no-cache libc6-compat
RUN apk update
WORKDIR /app
 
# First install the dependencies (as they change less often)
COPY .gitignore .gitignore
COPY --from=builder /app/out/json/ .
COPY --from=builder /app/out/package-lock.json ./package-lock.json
RUN npm ci
 
# Build the project
ARG MONOLITH_DOMAIN
ENV MONOLITH_DOMAIN=$MONOLITH_DOMAIN

COPY --from=builder /app/out/full/ .
COPY turbo.json turbo.json

RUN npx turbo run build --filter=admin
 
FROM node:alpine AS runner
WORKDIR /app
 
# Don't run production as root
RUN addgroup --system --gid 1001 nodejs
RUN adduser --system --uid 1001 nextjs
USER nextjs
 
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/admin/next.config.js .
COPY --from=installer /app/apps/admin/package.json .
 
# Automatically leverage output traces to reduce image size
# https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/output-file-tracing
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/admin/.next/standalone ./
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/admin/.next/static ./apps/admin/.next/static
COPY --from=installer --chown=nextjs:nodejs /app/apps/admin/public ./apps/admin/public
 
CMD node apps/admin/server.js
```

As recommendeded by https://turbo.build/repo/docs/handbook/deploying-with-docker

**My github action**

```
name: Build and Push Docker Image

on:
  workflow_call:
    inputs:
      environment:
        required: true
        type: string
      tag:
        required: true
        type: string
      monolith_domain:
        required: true
        type: string
    secrets:
      GOOGLE_CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_TOKEN:
        required: true

jobs:
  build-and-push:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - name: Check out code
      uses: actions/checkout@v3

    - name: Set up Docker Buildx
      uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

    - id: auth
      name: Authenticate to Google Cloud
      uses: google-github-actions/auth@v1
      with:
        token_format: access_token
        credentials_json: ${{ secrets.GOOGLE_CLOUD_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_JSON_TOKEN }}

    - uses: 'docker/login-action@v2'
      with:
        registry: europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev
        username: oauth2accesstoken
        password: ${{ steps.auth.outputs.access_token }}

    - name: Build and push Docker image
      uses: docker/build-push-action@v4
      with:
        context: .
        file: ./apps/admin/Dockerfile
        push: true
        tags: europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/xxxx/frontend/admin-frontend:${{ inputs.tag }}
        build-args: |
          MONOLITH_DOMAIN=${{ inputs.monolith_domain }}
```